# How to fix document broken content?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

I have been sent several files in order to fix them - the issue is that when they are opened you are not seeing the correct text and my cousin is not able to prepare for his exam.

So, I have found it very strange because it does not seem like wrong encoding that I have ever seen - I got only several repeating symbols like this:

[image]

In the other file, I have found one page with only "1", several pages with only "2" and one page with only "3" repeating the whole page.

Has anyone knew is it possible to recover the context using some program or tool?

The type of the document is ".doc"

EDIT: I have move the files to my Windows 7 machine and try to open them with Microsoft Office Word. What I have seen, was empty pages - when I selected some space, in the language bar the Word shows: "Russian". I suppose the lectures is with some Russian text my computers or office packet are not able to decode it. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you been able to open these on the original computer to confirm there is any content? You can open up a .doc file in a simple editor, but this looks like you have just a bunch of 1's and 2's

Comment: @RoryAlsop They have been sent to me by my cousin. My first thought was that some of his friends is making a joke with him, but he ensures me that the lectures have been given to him by his teacher. It still can be a joke with all of his students (typical for our country) - I just hope there is a real issue and someone has seen this behavior before.

Comment: If these came from a teacher, then the fastest way to resolve would be to contact the teacher and ask what software was used to create them, and if there are any specific encodings, fonts, etc that are necessary to open.  If we know this we can provide more directed help if you are still unable to open.  Otherwise we are just stabbing in the dark...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there are some issues with Open Office documents and Word files created in Russian.

Some folks at http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=15669 have posted a macro that might help in Open Office.

I'd recommend downloading the Russian language pack on your Windows 7 computer and seeing if that helps.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win7

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am pretty convinced this is the issue. Unfortunately, I was not able to fix my files. Anyway I have found some tool that can be useful to someone in the future - http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en